# Required validation not working in laravel darkaonline swagger UI

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi, api-doc

I am using `darkaonline/l5-swagger: 7.0` for generate swagger UI which based on `OpenApi 3.0`. But the problem is `required` validation only works for `path` params and not with form-data properties. I tried adding required property names in an array but it only shows `required` text in red color but not validates when execute.

```
/**
 * @OA\Post(
 *      path="/sign-in",
 *      operationId="signIn",
 *      tags={"Authentication"},
 *      summary="AuthenticationController@signIn",
 *      description="Login",
 *      @OA\RequestBody(
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\MediaType(mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  required={"email","password"},
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="email",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      description="Email"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="password",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      description="Password"
 *                  ),
 *             )
 *         )
 *      ),
 *       @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="Successful",
 *       ),
 *       @OA\Response(
 *          response=401,
 *          description="Unauthorized",
 *      ),
 *  )
 */
```

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to add the require statement on each of the fields using `required=true,` instead of `required={"email","password"},`?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Yeah. Then when I try to generate swagger UI I get `@OA\Property()->required is a "boolean", expecting a "[string]" ` error.

Comment: It seems you need to use `Form` instead of `Body` See: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object

Comment: @oluwatobi I tried. But no success.

Answer (score 0):

Use "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.0"
In this version, your validation will work properly.

You have marked the field as required is correct, no need to change.

PFA its working-
[image]